# How can we get multiple rows data as single row in oracle

Tags: oracle

[image]
In image I have given table structure and sample data and I need output result as mentioned

Comment: Consider : what is the relation between type 01 and type 02?  Are there other possible types?  If so, what are their relationships?  What if Gani had, instead of three type 01 records, had two type 01 and one type 02?  And  very importantly if you want assistance from volunteers - what have you tried so far?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: possible values for type are only 01 and 02 only, suppose employee Mohan visits library  (type 01) on 09/09/2010 and he visited lab(type 02) on 10/09/2010. so I need output as 1 Mohan 09/09/2010 10/09/2010 (id name library_date lab_date) like this. please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you provided (lines #1 - 8), this returns desired result. Will it work for all other cases, I have no idea as the question lacks in quite a lot of information so YMMV.

```
SQL> with employee (id, name, type, visit_date) as
  2    (select 1, 'Mohan', '01', date '2010-09-09' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'Mohan', '02', date '2010-09-10' from dual union all
  4     --
  5     select 1, 'Gani' , '01', date '2010-09-01' from dual union all
  6     select 1, 'Gani' , '01', date '2010-09-02' from dual union all
  7     select 1, 'Gani' , '01', date '2010-09-03' from dual
  8    ),
  9  --
 10  type1 as
 11    (select id, name, visit_date
 12     from employee
 13     where type = '01'
 14    ),
 15  type2 as
 16    (select id, name, visit_date
 17     from employee
 18     where type = '02'
 19    )
 20  select
 21    a.id,
 22    a.name,
 23    a.visit_date type1date,
 24    b.visit_date type2date
 25  from type1 a left join type2 b on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name
 26  order by a.id, a.name desc, a.visit_date;

        ID NAME  TYPE1DATE  TYPE2DATE
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
         1 Mohan 09/09/2010 10/09/2010
         1 Gani  01/09/2010
         1 Gani  02/09/2010
         1 Gani  03/09/2010

SQL>
```